# titanium maps user location near annotation

Tags: google-maps, titanium-mobile

Im building an app with titanium and i am creating multiple annotations on a google map.

My question is if somehow i can check if user location is inside an annotation and lets say fire an alert. Is this possible?

In a similar project with javascript i was creating circles around annotations and then checking if user was inside this circle.

Something like this:

```
Circles[k] = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    clickable: false,
    radius: 35,
    fillColor: '#fff',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    strokeColor: '#313131',
    strokeOpacity: .4,
    strokeWeight: .8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(json.markers[k].lat, json.markers[k].lon)
});
BoundsArray[k] = Circles[k].getBounds();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Geofencing (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/geofencing-with-core-location/)

Geofencing is the process in which one or more geofences are monitored and action is taken when a particular geofence is entered or exited. Geofencing is a technology very well suited for mobile devices. A good example is Apple’s Reminders application. You can attach a geofence to a reminder so that the application notifies you when you are in the vicinity of a particular location (figure 1). This is incredibly powerful and much more intuitive that using traditional reminders that remind you at a certain date or time.

IOS Module Implementation for Titanium:

http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/34758523489/appcelerator-titanium-quickie-ios-geofencing-module#.UZVL3CtARYg

I believe there is a tutorial on converting Skyhook's SDK to a module in Titanium.  This looks like the result.
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ClearlyInnovativeSkyhookModule